# Get latitude/longitude from zip code

Tags: java, json, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

Is there any way (any API or any URL) to find the lat, long by passing the area code (zip code) only?

Comment: The tearm you want to search for is "geocoding". (Note that some zipcodes are quite large - a single coordinate will not be a very accurate piece of data)

Comment: hey guys i have got answer http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="zipcode"&sensor=true

simple answer..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Maps Geocoder will search on just zipcode.

Here is an example: (and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQwCZ/1/) to see it working)

```
var geocoder;    
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            $('#coord').val(results[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: "
                  + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Google's free version of the API is restrictive when it comes to batch geocoding.  If you need to geocode lots of data you may want to look into a geocoding service like: [USC's geocoding service](https://webgis.usc.edu/Services/Geocode/WebService/GeocoderWebService.aspx).

Comment: can we return latlng object with in the if block....like..........return latlng;     i tried but not working any help around....

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use a database of this information; [here's a free one.](http://ipinfodb.com/zipcode_database.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the yahoo geoplanet dataset. It includes geocoded zipcodes worldwide and a few other things. The main problem with this dataset is that it is no longer maintained so it may be missing newer postalcodes.

Otherwise, you could use a geocoder indeed. Google, Navteq, and Yahoo have such APIs though I don't know if they can geocode just postcodes.