# Android Reverse Geocode

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding

How to get City, state information from Zip code (US) provided, is it possible using android libraries ? I would like to avoid using external libs if not necessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9714075/1777090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to use reverse Geocoding.

First get the lat, long from the zip code. See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187031/1369222

Then use the lat,long to get whatever else you need. See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409229/1369222